# Minimum value of socks

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a box with socks black and blue. We are gonna take off two socks of the box, no looking. What is the minimum number of socks of each color if we desire that the probability of the two socks chosen are blue is $\frac{1}{2}.$

In my approach I get that the solution is $3$ socks blue and $1$ sock black, but I don't know if it is right.

Comment: The numbers of blue and black are right.

Comment: Hi @AndréNicolas, is this right then?

Comment: I wrote that the numbers you got are right. If it is a homework question, you would probably be expected to show the reasoning.

Comment: Is more like a challenge! I know how to solve, I just wanted to see if my solution holds. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ denote the number of blue socks.

Let $y$ denote the number of black socks.

Then the following condition must hold:

$$\frac{\binom{x}{2}}{\binom{x+y}{2}}=\dfrac12$$

We know that $x\geq2$, so let's start with $x=2$ and $y=1$:

$$\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{2+1}{2}}=\frac13<\frac12$$

There's no point increasing the value of $y$, so let's try $x=3$:

$$\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{3+1}{2}}=\frac12$$

Hence the minimum amount is $x=3$ blue socks and $y=1$ black sock.